# Use apply with table in R

Tags: r, mapply

I have two variables, one is dependent and another one is independent variable. The dependent variable is `x` and the independent variable is `y`. The dependent variable is itself a matrix and it can be iterated as `x[,1:n]`; same goes for the independent variable .The independent variable can be iterated as `y[,1:n]`. Now for one single instance of the variable - I would use the table function in R to find ROC like so : `table(y[,1], round(x[,1])`. I want to use apply function out here so that I can iterate both the variables at the same time - something like `apply(ind_var,dep_var,2,function(x,y){x,round(y)})` This can easily be done using a for loop - can it be done using `apply`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try using `sapply`:

```
sapply(1:ncol(x), function(i) table(y[,i], round(x[,i]))
```

Comment: Can I use mapply in this - mapply seems more plausible to use.

Comment: I am getting this error: All argument must have the same length.

Comment: It really depends on your data structure. From what you described, x and y have the same number of columns. If this is not true, but the error you are getting says otherwise. If you are thinking of using `mapply`, the same equal length of arguments should hold. As a side note, I've often found `Map()` easier to use than `mapply()`.